# Unable to see the delay in the node js program

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node js ,and I started with below program ,

I wanted to see how the delay or parallel execution works , so I took a program from the tutorial website and my expected out was

1. Place order 1 Here it will wait for 3 seconds
2. Place order 2 Here it will wait for 3 more seconds , thus 6 seconds expired
3. Delivering order Number 1 (since the first Timeout of 5 seconds
   expired)
4. Place order 3  And so on , here we take 2 orders and deliver the
   order
       after 6 seconds that after 5 seconds are over

But I get below output

1. Order numner is 1 //3 sec delay
2. Order numner is 2 //3 sec delay
3. Order numner is 3 //3 sec delay
4. Order numner is 4 //3 sec delay
5. Order numner is 5 //3 sec delay
6. Delivering order Number 1 //no delay
7. Delivering order Number 2 //no delay
8. Delivering order Number 3 //no delay
9. Delivering order Number 4 //no delay
10. Delivering order Number 5

    ```
    function  placeOrder(orderNumber) {
        console.log('Order numner is ' +orderNumber);
        cookAndDeliverFood(function () {
        console.log('Delivering order Number ' +orderNumber);
        })
    }

    function  cookAndDeliverFood( callback) {
        setTimeout(callback , 1000);
        var waitTill = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3 * 1000);
        while(waitTill > new Date()){}

    }

    placeOrder(1);
    placeOrder(2);
    placeOrder(3);
    placeOrder(4);
    placeOrder(5);
    ```

Can someone please explain why the setTimeOut(callback,5000) doesnot gets called back immediatedly after 5 seconds , Why does it wait for taking all the orders and the Deliver the oder , wht cant it deliver the TimedOut orders ?

Could you please help me to implement a code whic can give me expected output as I mentioned above?

Comment: Never, ever do this in node.js `while(waitTill > new Date()){}`.  Since JS in node.js is single threaded, this will just loop your server and be able to do nothing else in the meantime.  It is always the wrong way to program in node.js.  Use timeouts to schedule code to run in the future and then other can can run in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` will put a function on a heap where it will be run after:

- A certain amount of time has passed *and*
- The event loop isn't busy doing something else

Since JavaScript is busy running the `while` loop, it won't run any functions waiting for a timeout. It will finish running that function first.

Use timeouts to create delays instead.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.
Now I get the significance of single threaded event loop.